# AppStartError: CreateProcess: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, pywinauto, sap-gui

Using pywinauto to automate a SAP extract. I swear this code -- copied right out of SWAPY -- worked yesterday.

```
from pywinauto.application import Application

app = Application().Start(cmd_line = u"C:\\'Program Files (x86)'\\SAP\\FrontEnd\\SAPgui\\saplogon.exe")
window = app.Dialog
window.Wait('ready')
edit = window.Edit
edit.ClickInput()
```

This gives me the following error:

> error:
> Traceback (most recent call last)
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py
> in start(self, cmd_line, timeout, retry_interval, create_new_console,
> wait_for_idle, work_dir)
> 991                 work_dir,                               # If None - use parent's starting directory.
> --> 992                 start_info)               # STARTUPINFO structure.
> 993         except Exception as exc:
>
> error: (2, 'CreateProcess', 'The system cannot find the file
> specified.')
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> AppStartError                             Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> 1 from pywinauto.application import Application
> 2
> ----> 3 app = Application().Start(cmd_line=u"C:\'Program Files (x86)''\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\saplogon.exe")
> 4 window = app.Dialog
> 5 window.Wait('ready')
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py
> in start(self, cmd_line, timeout, retry_interval, create_new_console,
> wait_for_idle, work_dir)
> 995             message = ('Could not create the process "%s"\n'
> 996                        'Error returned by CreateProcess: %s') % (cmd_line, str(exc))
> --> 997             raise AppStartError(message)
> 998
> 999         self.process = dw_process_id
>
> AppStartError: Could not create the process "C:'Program Files
> (x86)''\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\saplogon.exe" Error returned by
> CreateProcess: (2, 'CreateProcess', 'The system cannot find the file
> specified.')

I'm running Win7 64bit with Python 3.6.4 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit) and pywingui release 222. I can cut and paste  the command into a cmd window and it starts the application just fine.

I've changed quotes. I changed the string to raw and removed the `\\` for a single `\` I'm phlummoxxed.

Also - yesterday when it "worked", clicking on the elements in the 740 version of SAP GUI is a real challenge. Is there any trick to overcome how they have obfuscated the user interface?

Comment: Changing  `u"C:\\'Program Files (x86)'\\SAP\\FrontEnd\\SAPgui\\saplogon.exe"` to  `r'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\SAP\\FrontEnd\\SAPgui\\saplogon.exe'` resolved the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing  `u"C:\\'Program Files (x86)'\\SAP\\FrontEnd\\SAPgui\\saplogon.exe"` to  `r'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\SAP\\FrontEnd\\SAPgui\\saplogon.exe'` resolved the issue